# iOS Objective C - should coordinators and models inherit from NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been developing in Swift for almost a year now and I've decided to pick up objective C. However, I've ran into a problem. I make my own coordinator class in swift which I use to pretty much coordinate the entire application, however when i make the class without inheriting NSObject in obj C i cannot alloc it. Is there any detriment to inheriting from NSObject? What if I make for example a model Animal for my tableview that displays a list of animals? Should that model inherit NSObject as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in general, you'd want all your objects to inherit from NSObject (or some subclass of NSObject). NSObject is the root class of almost all Objective-C objects.

Making your model a subclass of NSObject will give it the ability to be an object as far as Objective-C is concerned.